# Sort a matrix by a column in Octave

Tags: arrays, sorting, if-statement, recursion, octave

I have to create a recursive (using 'if', not 'for' or 'while' allowed) function in Octave (similar to Matlab) that sort the n rows of an array (the entry is just the array) by one of its columns. I get stuck in the recursive step.

```
function Msorted=sort_array(M)
  [n,m]=size(M);
  if n<2
    Msorted=M
  else
```

Basically my question would be, how should I write my recursive step, how should I continue?

Comment: There is no question in your post. Please be explicit when asking a question. See [ask], and make sure to show your work, it helps understand how to answer.

Comment: What do you mean "by one of its columns"? Which one?

Comment: By a generic column, for example it could be the column 'm'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we sort the array according to the `m` column:

```
% This is a recursive function, too:
function min_index = get_min_index(column_vec)
   if size(column_vec, 1)<2
      min_index = 1;
   else % `column_vec` contains at least 2 elements
      first = column_vec(1);
      new_vec = column_vec(2:end); % `new_vec` is `column_vec` without the first element
      min_index_new = get_min_index(new_vec); % get the index of the min number of `new_vec`
      if first<=new_vec(min_index_new)
         min_index = 1;
      else
         min_index = min_index_new + 1; % we need to add 1 becuase `new_vec` does not include the first element of `column_vec`
      end
   end
end

function Msorted = sort_array(M)
   n = size(M, 1);
   if n<2
      Msorted = M;
   else
      min_index = get_min_index(M(:, m)); % Find the index of the minimum value in the m_th column
      M_new = M(1:n~=min_index, :); % `M_new` is `M` without the "minimum row" that should be the first row in `Msorted`
      M_new_sorted = sort_array(M_new); % Sort `M_new`
      Msorted = [M(min_index, :); M_new_sorted]; % Add back the "minimum row" to `M_new`
   end
end
```

**Example** (for `m = 2`):

Code:

```
a = [200 -4; 400 -100; -50 -1000]
a_sort = sort_array(a)
```

Output:

```
a =

    200     -4
    400   -100
    -50  -1000

a_sort =

    -50  -1000
    400   -100
    200     -4
```

Note that you can use the `sortrows` function without recursion, like `Msorted = sortrows(x, m)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is an interesting idea (using the function 'min'); this helped me to see the problem by other perspective, is like a Quick Sort algorithm using the min as the pivot. How could I modify your code to one that doesn't depend of the function min, like using any number of the column 'k' as pivot?

Comment: You can change the input to `sort_array(M, k)` and pass the number of the column you want into the function. However, if you don't want to use `min` at all, you can implement it yourself. I can add such an implementation to my answer if you want.

Comment: I would love it! The idea is not to change the input.

Comment: I added the implementation (without loops), and also changed 'k' to 'm'. Note that the solution is still based on the index `m` and you need to define it. It is not possible to choose a specific column without saying your choice explicitly. Only if `m` has a constant value you will be able to define it at the start of the function instead of passing it as input.

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped me a lot! Recursion is kind of difficult to understand if you are as bad as me coding.

Comment: If you will train enough (the number of training changes from one person to another) and see more and more recursive functions, you will get the concept and be able to write your own recursions. Don't give up!